# Filtering the calendar items base on checkbox

Tags: list, list-view, filter, sharepoint-calendar, calendar-view

I have a SharePoint calendar for activities which users choose in a column (Choice) what platform is that activity IE. Windows, Unix, Network and so on.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to filter this using a check box? For example I have checked all the checkbox below. It will only show those items with Windows, Unix and Network.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using OOTB functionalities of SharePoint then I will suggest you to **create a new List View and add filters** based on the choice column selection (This is easy and no-code workaround for your requirement).

To Modify Current View, Follow below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list (Calendar view).
2. click on **CALENDAR** from top ribbon.
3. Click on **Modify View**.
   [image]
4. Scroll down to **Filter** section and add filter like below (As per your column names and values):
   [image]

To fulfill your requirements you can create multiple view and set the filter like given above.

Follow below official documentation on how to create and modify the list views in SharePoint:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Ganesh but we are currently using this filter method and overlaying them. But our users want to have a filter like checkbox. As our default it is showing all the activities but when they uncheck one of the platforms it will remove that from the view. Is that possible?

Comment: I am afraid but this is not possible using OOTB capabilities of SharePoint. You may need to develop custom solution to achieve something you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on creating a clearer answer:

1. Create Yes/No column with field to filter
   [image: Create Yes/No Column with field to filter]
2. Create calendar view to filter values you want (or exclude)
   [image: Create Calendar View]
   [image: Set Filter Parameters]
3. Add calendar to another view as an overlay
   [image: Add Calendar overlays to current view]
4. Add items and check box as necessary.
   [image: Create Calendar Item]